# inserted field change in the parent is not triggering the workflow on the child

Tags: workflow, formula-field

I’m working on tagging child objects with a checkbox and a date/time field. The checkbox is working. What I am trying to do now, is fill out a date/time field when the checkbox “included in PO” is checked.

I have an insert-update field that grabs the NOW() timestamp on a DDP creation. The child object then has a formula of 
`IF(CreatedDate <= Estimate__r.CompOne_PO_Created__c, TRUE, FALSE)` to automatically check the box when that DDP is run.

I then created a workflow rule `(Repair Material: Included in CompOne POEQUALSTrue)` and a field update to add the timestamp to a “date added to PO” field. For some reason, this last field update will not work.

It only works if the DDP is run and then I edit the object. It will not add the date if the formula does it. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying that when the parent object is updated, you would like the date of that change to be recorded on the child object? Would you settle for a date formula on the child object, rather than a date field?

Comment: I don't think that's exactly what I'm saying... Only because I need to preserve the older child objects original date when checked... Otherwise a date formula would work.

i.e. new child objects would not be checked until the DDP is run, and once it is run it should check the child objects and add the date. Thanks @JeremyNottingham

Comment: Is Repair Material: Included in CompOne PO a formula field with a checkbox return type, or a checkbox field whose value is set via a workflow field update?

Comment: checkbox whose value is set via workflow field update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Now()` is a `DateTime` while if you want a `Date`, then you want to to use `Today()` in your formula. I suggest you make certain which `type` your field is set to accept. If it's a string or text field, then you need to get `TEXT(Today())` or `TEXT(Now())` when you try to assign it to your field. I strongly suspect that's the problem you're having.

Comment: Sorry, they are both DateTime fields.This isn't the problem. The problem is that the DDP inserted field change in the parent is not triggering the workflow on the child.

Comment: Is this a M-D relationship to the child or does the child have a look-up to the parent?

Comment: M-D relationship

Comment: Ok. So you have a many to one relationship with the parent and you're clicking a checkbox on the child's record in the related list while looking at the Parent's Detail Record? In essence, how are you passing the child record's ID to workflow for it to know which child record to to update with the time stamp?

Comment: The workflow field update to add the timestamp is on the child record itself. Basically the DDP inserted field change it not triggering this workflow. I'm thinking I need a trigger to do this?

Comment: The DDP inserted field is an update to the child record or is it an extra field that's created on the child record when the box is checked? Is the checkbox on the child record or on the Parent? I'm now very confused as to where the checkbox is, what object's record is being updated and what object's record or field is being inserted.

Comment: Boy this does get confusing quick, my apologies. 

1) The DDP inserted field update (a timestamp) is on the parent object
2) The formula field (checkbox) that references the parent's timestamp is on the child object. 'IF(CreatedDate <= Estimate__r.CompOne_PO_Created__c, TRUE, FALSE)'

What I am having difficulty with is a workflow field update that updates 3) ANOTHER timestamp field on the child when 2 is checked.

Comment: In my experience, you're probably going to need a trigger and you'll need to figure out how to accommodate multiple child records when you write the trigger if they exist. If they don't, then the trigger will be easy to write.

Comment: Gotch ya, thank you very much for hashing that out with me!